# codeigniter where_not_in not working

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I pass an array to my model and I want to get the employee_id s which are not in that array. Also 'position' field should be equal to 'c'.

Following is my table:

[image: emp_position table]

Following is my model.   $evdata is a number passed to the model to limit the selecting records. Also the array $data is json encoded array.

public function get_camaramens($data,$evdata)
{

```
$this->db->select('emp_position.employee_id');
$this->db->from('emp_position');
$this->db->where('emp_position.position','c');
$this->db->where_not_in('emp_position.employee_id',$data);
$query=$this->db->get('',$evdata);
return $query->result();
```

}

It doesn't give a correct result. So I removed the following part and checked.

```
$this->db->where_not_in('emp_position.employee_id',$data);
```

Both times it gives the same result. It seems only the first where condition is working.

Following is the var_dump result of both times:
[image: Following is the var_dump result of both times.]

After adding the code

```
$data                   = $this->emp_event_model->get_current_employees($date);

$newData = array();
foreach($data as $row) {
    $newData[] = $row['employee_id'];
    }
$data = $newData;
```

It gives this error:

[image]

Comment: can you `var_dump($data);` see whats the result of `$data`

Comment: array (size=5) <br/>
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[26]
      public 'employee_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[27]
      public 'employee_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[28]
      public 'employee_id' => string '7' (length=1)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[29]
      public 'employee_id' => string '8' (length=1)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[30]
      public 'employee_id' => string '9' (length=1)

Comment: you're $data array must be in `array(1, 2, 3)` format not `array('employee_id' => 1, 'employee_id' => 2, etc...)`

Comment: @NewbeeDev  How to  convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `$data` array must be in this format

```
array(2, 3, 7, 8, 9)
```

but your array is

```
array (size=5) 
0 => object(stdClass)[26] public 'employee_id' => string '2' (length=1) 
1 => object(stdClass)[27] public 'employee_id' => string '3' (length=1) 
2 => object(stdClass)[28] public 'employee_id' => string '7' (length=1) 
3 => object(stdClass)[29] public 'employee_id' => string '8' (length=1) 
4 => object(stdClass)[30] public 'employee_id' => string '9' (length=1)
```

so restructure your array inside your controller

```
$newData = array();
foreach($data as $row) {
    $newData[] = $row->employee_id;
}
$data = $newData;
```

so this will become

```
array(2, 3, 7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: It gives this array  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @Christeen what it gives? can you should a screen shot of your code of how you restructure the array

Comment: I think it should be $newData[] = $row->employee_id; as it is an object not an array

Comment: @Christeen ah it error because employee_id is not an index it is an object. I just updated my answer

Comment: Solved the problem. THANK U both Nawbee Dev & Abdul Haseeb !

Comment: @NewbeeDev No your code is correct but had to update it with Abdul Haseeb's answer.